# How to read Hive Hbase table from Spark with scala

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hbase

I am trying to read hive hbase table through spark dataframe. I have added all reqired dependencies. But still its failing with below error:

```
    ERROR log: error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException 
Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found  
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found
```

Below is the sbt dependency:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-hbase-handler
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-hbase-handler" % "3.1.0"
```

And the spark code is :

```
spark.sql("Select * from video_analytics.video_creator_map").show()
```

I have created the `video_creator_map` table in hbase and created a hive external table with a same name and serde properties '`org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler`'.

I am able to run the above query in hive and getting the result. But the same query is giving error when i am running through spark. I am using spark with scala here.

Comment: Have you refer this: https://blog.cloudera.com/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/

Comment: i have used the package mentioned in the blog but its still giving me the same error

Comment: `I have added all reqired dependencies.` - you mean in sbt, or also in spark-submit? (just making sure)